# Change name JSON in array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to rename the json but it generates the following error

```
var kvArray = [
{0: 'cat',  1: 1, 2: "sunt"},
{0: 'dog',  1: 2, 2: "qui"},
{0: 'mouse',1: 3, 2: "repell"}
];

var newArray = kvArray.map((elm) => {
var mappedElm = { animal: elm.0, age: elm.1, name: elm.2};
return mappedElm;
});

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Could you please post the error? Now it's an incomplete question.

Comment: `error: unknown: Unexpected token, expected "," (9:33) 7 | 8 | let newArray = kvArray.map((elm) => { > 9 | let mappedElm = { animal: elm.0, age: elm.1, name: elm.2}; | ^ 10 | return mappedElm; 11 | }); 12 | console.log(newArray)`

Comment: please use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57592425/edit) if you want to add content to your question

Comment: `var newArray = kvArray.map(elm => ({animal: elm[0], age: elm[1], name: elm[2]}));` This works and is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object represented in the JSON is an numerically indexed array, not an object.

You probably need to use the [] index contstruct as follows

```
var kvArray = [
{0: 'cat',  1: 1, 2: "sunt"},
{0: 'dog',  1: 2, 2: "qui"},
{0: 'mouse',1: 3, 2: "repell"}
];

var newArray = kvArray.map((elm) => {
var mappedElm = { animal: elm[0], age: elm[1], name: elm[2]};
return mappedElm;
});

console.log(newArray)
```